# Probablity on String

Tags: probability

> Find the probability that a randomly generated bit string of length 10 does not contain a 0 if bits are independent and if:
>
> a)  a $0$ bit and a $1$ bit are equally likely
>
> b)  the probability that a bit is a $1$ is $0.6$
>
> c)  the  probability  that  the  $i^{th}$  bit  is  a  $1$  is  $\frac{1}{2i}$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, \dots$

My approach:

a) $P(\text{String not containing } 0) = 1/2^{10}(1111111111)$

b) $P(\text{String not containing } 0) = 0.6^{10}$

c) $P(\text{String not containing } 0) = \prod_{i=1}^{10}(1/2)^{i}$

Is this correct?

Comment: They are all correct.

Comment: Thank you for verifying it @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: You are welcome, @sourav.

Comment: are you sure about c?

Comment: for c, if you had a 3 bit string (to make it quicker), then it would be (1/2)(1/4)(1/6) - but your pi formula gives (1/2)(1/4)(1/8) - where are your factors like 3,5,7 etc coming from?  If the i in (c) is an exponent not a factor, it might explain it

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Please check more carefully before validating answers (here, the answer to (c) is wrong). (Especially since two users upvote comments with at least as much care...)

Comment: @Did The question has been edited since I Iast answered this question. The earlier question had a $2^i$ instead of $2i$ (and I'm quite sure).Even those up voting my comment must have seen the old question. I do check answers before posting, but thank you anyway for the friendly reminder.